# Beautiful sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

A sequence of integers is beautiful if each element of this sequence is divisible by `4`.You are given a sequence `a1, a2, ..., an`. In one step, you may choose any two elements of this sequence, remove them from the sequence and append their sum to the sequence. Compute the minimum number of steps necessary to make the given sequence beautiful else print `-1` if this is not possible.

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
    if((sum(arr))%4)!=0:
        print(-1)
        continue
    else:
        counter=[]
        for i in range(n):
            if arr[i]%4!=0:
                counter.append(arr[i])
            else:
                continue

        x=sum(counter)
        while(x%4==0):
            x=x//4

        print(x)
```

My approach:if the sum of the array is not divisible by `4` then the array can not be beautiful else  if the sum of the array mod `4` is equal to zero i count the elements in the array whose mod by 4 is not equal to zero and append them in the list and then find the sum  of the list and divide the sum by 4 till its quotient modulus 4 is not equal to zero.what i am doing wrong here?

Edit:I have a working script which works well

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
    count1=0
    count2=0
    count3=0
    summ=0
    for i in range(n):
        x=arr[i]%4
        summ+=x


        if x==1:
            count1+=1

        if x==2:
            count2+=1

        if x==3:
            count3+=1
    if (summ%4)!=0:
        print(-1)
        continue

    else:


        if count2==0 and count1!=0 and count3==0:
            tt=count1//4
            print(3*tt)

        if count2==0 and count1==0 and count3!=0:
            tt=count3//4
            print(3*tt)

        if count2%2==0 and count1==count3:
            print(count2//2+count1)

        flag1=min(count1,count3)
        flag2=abs(count1-count3)

        if count2%2==0 and count1!=count3:

            flag3=flag2//4
            flag4=flag3*3

            print(count2//2+ flag1+ flag4)

        if count2%2!=0 and count1!=count3:
            flag3=flag2-2
            flag4=flag3//4
            flag5=flag4*3


            print(((count2-1)//2)+flag1+flag5+2)
```

Comment: problem:https://www.codechef.com/problems/BTAR

Comment: What does your algorithm return for `[1,2,3,2]`?

Comment: @n.m. Wouldn't it just be `2`?

Comment: @RoadRunner hmm yes, I didn't understand the program. But then it prints `1` for `1 1 1 1` so it seems wrong in a different way.

Comment: @n.m. for [1,2,3,2] it should be 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First some observations:

- For the sake of 4-divisibility, we can replace all numbers by their division-by-4 remainder, so we only have to cope with values 0, 1, 2 and 3.
- The ordering doesn't matter, counting the zeroes, ones, twos and threes is enough.
- There are pairs immediately giving a sum divisible by 4: (1, 3) and (2, 2). Each existence of such a pair needs one step.
- There are triples (1, 1, 2) and (3, 3, 2) needing two steps.
- There are quadruples (1, 1, 1, 1) and (3, 3, 3, 3) needing three steps.

Algorithm:

- Count the remainder-0 (can be omitted), remainder-1, remainder-2 and remainder-3 numbers.
- If the total sum (from the counts) isn't divisible by 4, there's no solution.
- For all the N-tuples described above, find how often they fit into the counts; add the resulting number of steps, subtract the numbers consumed from the counts.

Finally, the remainder-1, remainder-2 and remainder-3 counts should be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an O(N) implementation going pretty much in the direction suggested by [Ralf Kleberhoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8207228/ralf-kleberhoff):

```
from collections import Counter

def beautify(seq):
    # only mod4 is interesting, count 1s, 2s, and 3s
    c = Counter(x % 4 for x in seq)
    c1, c2, c3 = c.get(1, 0), c.get(2, 0), c.get(3, 0)
    steps22, twos = divmod(c2, 2)  # you have either 0 or 1 2s left
    steps13, ones_or_threes = min(c1, c3), abs(c1 - c3)
    if not twos and not ones_or_threes % 4:
        # 3 steps for every quadruple of 1s or 3s
        return steps22 + steps13 + 3 * ones_or_threes // 4  
    if twos and ones_or_threes % 2 == 2:
        # 2 extra steps to join the remaining 2 1s or 3s with the remaining 2
        return steps22 + steps13 + 3 * ones_or_threes // 4 + 2
    return -1
```

Comment: Nice,The solution is more pythonic :)

Comment: But your script fails on some of the test cases.I have a working script now but thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your issue is, but perhaps you could change your approach to the problem. Your logic seems fine, but it seems that your trying to do everything in one go, this problem would be much easier if you break it down into pieces. It looks like it would fit a divide and conquer / recursive approach quite nicely. I also took the liberty of solving this problem myself, as it seems like a fun question to attempt.

**Suggestions below**

First thing you could do is write a function that finds two numbers that has a sum divisible by `k`, and return them:

```
def two_sum(numbers, k):
    n = len(numbers)

    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if (numbers[i] + numbers[j]) % k == 0:
                return numbers[i], numbers[j]
    return None
```

Furthermore, the above function is `O(n^2)`, this could be made more efficient.

Secondly, you could write a recursive function that uses the above function, and has a base case where it stops recursing when all the numbers in the list are divisible by `k`, therefore the list has become *"beautiful"*. Here is one way of doing this:

```
def rec_helper(numbers, k, count):
    if all(x % k == 0 for x in numbers):
        return count

    # probably safer to check if two_sum() is not None here
    first, second = two_sum(numbers, k)

    numbers.remove(first)
    numbers.remove(second)
    numbers.append(first + second)

    return rec_helper(numbers, k, count + 1)
```

**Procedure of above code**

- Base case: if all the items in the list are currently divisible by `k`, return the current accumulated `count`.
- Otherwise, obtain a pair of integers whose sum is divisible by `k` from `two_sum()`
- `remove()` these two numbers from the list, and `append()` them to the end of the list.
- Finally, call `rec_helper()` again, with the new modified list and `count` incremented by one , which is `count + 1`. `count` here is the minimum number of steps.

Lastly, you can now write a main calling function:

```
def beautiful_array(numbers, k):
    if sum(numbers) % k != 0:
        return -1

    return rec_helper(numbers, k, 0)
```

Which first checks that the `sum()` of the numbers in the list is divisible by `k`, before proceeding to calling `rec_helper()`. If it doesn't pass this test, the function simply returns `-1`, and the list cannot be made *"beautiful"*.

**Behavior of above code**

```
>>> beautiful_array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 8], 4)
3
>>> beautiful_array([1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 8], 4)
2
>>> beautiful_array([1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 8], 4)
-1
```

**Note:** The above code examples are just suggestions, you can follow or use it however you want to. It also doesn't handle the `input()`, since I believe the main issue in your code is the approach. I didn't want to create a whole new solution that handles your input as well. Please comment below if their is something wrong with the above code, or if you don't understand anything.

Comment: Your program fails on `[1,1,1,1]` too.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, very well spotted. I knew their was something wrong with it.